# I am geting an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I am having trouble here. I added it in the windows_loaded event. The code goes here:

```
con.Open();
int i = 0, j = 0;
string[] productCode = null;
string[] productName = null;
int[] quantity =null;
float[] totalPrice = null;
float[] totalTax = null;
int orderID = 0;

SqlCeCommand com5 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details", con);
orderID = (int)com5.ExecuteScalar(); 
SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductCode, Quantity FROM Order_Products WHERE OrderID = ('"+ orderID.ToString() +"')", con);
SqlCeDataReader dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader();

while (dr1.Read())
{
    productCode[i] = (string)dr1[0];    // Exception is here
    quantity[i] = (int)dr1[1];
    SqlCeCommand com3 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products_Master WHERE ProductCode = '" + productCode[i] + "'", con);
    productName[i] = (string)com3.ExecuteScalar(); 
    i++;
}

SqlCeCommand com2 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TotalPrice, TotalTax FROM Order_Details WHERE OrderID = (SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details)", con);
SqlCeDataReader dr2 = com1.ExecuteReader();

while (dr2.Read())
{
    totalPrice[j] = (float)dr2[0];
    totalTax[j] = (float)dr2[1];
    j++;
}

for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
{
    List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
    Product p = new Product
    {
        ID = k,
        ProductName = productName[k],
        Quantity = quantity[k],
        Tax = totalTax[k],
        Total = totalPrice[k]
    };
    dgrdInvoice.Items.Add(p); // add a row
}

con.Close();
```

Can any one find me a solution for this issue? I am trying to add values from two database to a single DataGrid.

**Edit:**

Actually there is something in the SQL query:

> The datatype is not valid for the boolean expression. [Datatype (if known) = int , datatype (if unknown) = nvarchar].

Comment: which line? did you try using break points to see where is the problem??

Comment: After while (dr1.Read()). It is commented in the code.

Comment: Lot of things are wrong in this code. You need to refactor your code a lot, you cannot put everything in windows_loaded, need to use parameterised queries, and lot of explicit type casting which can go wrong... Finally `dr1` does not have any records fetched which is causing the problem. Execute the query in DB directly and see if the table returns any value

Comment: Bharath: you're correct regarding the refactoring but absolutely wrong about the DataReader. It's in the while(Read()) statement. If no records are fetched, that code wouldn't even be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
string[] productCode = null;
```

and never assign any real array to that variable. The same goes for your other "arrays".

Note that you can't change the length of an array, once created. You might need to look into the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare productName[]  array length means have to initialize array length .

Comment: you are assigning  productCode[i] =SOMEVALUE (here what is i) , which position. because array has no i position.

Comment: incrementing from 0 to till data is fetched. Is the array declaration error?

Comment: you have to declare array with some length. like string[] productName = new string[COUND OF YOUR RECORDS]; but you should use List<string> instead of array because you can't increase array length.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are converting OrderID to string, and that in your database the OrderID is an integer.

That you your query is not really good...

```
orderID = (int)com5.ExecuteScalar(); 
SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductCode, Quantity FROM Order_Products WHERE OrderID = "+ orderID+")", con);
```

or something very similar to this....

Answer (score 0):

### Declarations

Before using your variables, they should be instantiated. You cannot do this:

```
string[] productCode = null;
productCode[0] = "KD48Y";
//This results in: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

This will work:

```
string[] productCode = new string[3]; //can contain 3 strings
productCode[0] = "KD48Y";
```

But in your case I suggest you use a `List<T>`, otherwise you cannot increase the size of your array when you reach the initial limit.

### Query

This:

```
SqlCeCommand com5 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details", con);
orderID = (int)com5.ExecuteScalar(); 
SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductCode, Quantity FROM Order_Products WHERE OrderID = ('"+ orderID.ToString() +"')", con);
SqlCeDataReader dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
```

can be replaced by this:

```
SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductCode, Quantity FROM Order_Products 
                                      WHERE OrderID = (SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1
                                                       FROM Order_Details)", con);
```

### SqlDataReader

For getting values from your datareader-object, I'd suggest you use the proper method for this, Like `GetString()` or `GetInt32()`. More info on this: [**SqlDataReader Methods**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### Exception handling

You better use exception handling when interacting with datasources like a SQL-database or other operations that micht cause exceptions.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...");
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("...");
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
//other instantiations

try
{
    connection.Open();
    sql.ExecuteScalar();
    //other operations
}
catch (Ecxeption ex)
{
    //handle exception and show a message to the user
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    //this will always execute, even when an exception occurs
    //good for closing used resources
    connection.Close();
}
```

I hope this gets you on the way! ;)